# Access-Control-Allow-Origin appearing twice on header request ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

One one of my ASP.NET Web API controllers. I am getting the following error returned on my client application:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *',
>   but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

I recognise that this error occurs because the header contains multiple values. I can see this in the  'Response Headers' when the call is made to the API via Chrome, it looks like this:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Pragma,
>   Cache-Control, Authorization
>
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
>
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,
>   Accept, Authorization
>
> Set-Cookie:
>   ARRAffinity=ef9b3770b61f10f9696b0dedcb39a7f47a83c0e4d6cdbf367f3149482592ef06;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=seirse.azurewebsites.net

As you can see, it's clearly there twice.

The problem I have is that the only place I have enabled CORS is via the web.config in my application, e.g.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

I have made 100% sure that I have not enabled CORS via Startup.cs nor in the controller either.

There is nothing out of the ordinary with the controller as far as I can see:

```
// GET: api/Address/all
[HttpGet]
public AddressResultModel All()
{
    try
    {
        var userId = _accountService.GetUserId(Request);
        return _customerRepository.GetAddresses(userId);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: What happens if you add a `<clear />` to the top of the `<customHeaders>` element?

Comment: It still didn't work, however you've made me realise I had some CORS configuration values sitting over in my Application_BeginRequest method in Global.asax.cs. I commented this out and have got one step further - now getting a '405 Method Not Allowed' for OPTIONS method. Thank you I'm a bit further now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I had code inside my **Global.asax.cs** which was adding headers to the response for OPTIONS HTTP requests.

The reason I added this code was due to a separate issue whereby I was getting a "405 Method Not Allowed" error message for OPTIONS HTTP requests.

To fix both issues, I removed the code which was adding the extra headers and trimmed it down to this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Pragma, Cache-Control, Authorization ");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error because my endpoint returned response directly from another request, as a result my cors filter adds new headers  to the received response with the existing filters:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity getOmdbSearch(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParamMap, Principal principal) {
... ... ...

// Here an error !
return restTemplate.getForEntity(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString(), String.class);
}
```

I fixed it by returning result only:

```
@GetMapping
public String getOmdbSearch(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParamMap,
                            Principal principal) {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString(), String.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```