# Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest, cors

For reference I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10.

I have a web api and corresponding web application with user accounts. When I attempted to login I was met with an error which said No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present. I found a guide that walked me through how to setup CORS. This is the guide I used.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33771.fix-to-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-or-working-with-cross-origin-request-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx

In my WebApiConfig file I have this code

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
```

In my AccountController file I added in the EnableCors at the top.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
```

Finally, in my Web.config file I added the following:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This fixed my login issue however, none of my GETS are working. Here is an example of a GET function:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", 'http://localhost:60690/api/ProfilePicture?Username=' + username, false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
        xmlhttp.send();
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            returnValue = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
```

The GET is throwing an error which says "Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers are not allowed for CORS response". I don't see where I have multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers anywhere. Where should I be looking?

**Update 1**

Found something interesting. I used Fiddler to watch everything going on in the background and on the GET function that causes the error I'm seeing this in the headers:

[image]

So the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" is definitely showing twice but the question is why. I searched all of my code and I only have that declared once. If I remove that line, it breaks the login page so I have to leave it in.

Comment: Check my approach - it may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72311362/8186246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out. I went into the WebApiConfig file and changed the part about CORS to this:

```
//var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
//config.EnableCors(cors);
config.EnableCors();
```

Then I removed the EnableCors part from my Controller and it sort of started working again. I'm still getting an error on the GET call but I went from two errors to just one so it's progress I guess.