# .Net Core 2.0 Web API not working published in Azure becouse CORS with multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Response Headers

Tags: jquery, azure, web, cors, .net-core

I have been testing with a Web API backend built in .Net Core 2.0 and a simple web app using jQuery Ajax (version 3.2.1) with CORS enabled. Testing locally between two different machines it works great. After publishing in Azure Web Services (just the Web API, the Web App is local yet) without any change, the application fails and the browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox) complains about a multiple "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the header:

> "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values"

Using Fiddler,  I can see in the repeated header.

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8079
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

I have been hours investigating and browsing other cases in Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to apply.

This one is exactly the same problem but it is using ASP.Net MVC for its web API and the configuration and setup of its solution do not apply for .Net Core: [Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origen in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674549/multiple-access-control-allow-origin-headers).

My Javascript Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: uri_target_azure,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(contact),
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert("Success!" + result);
    }
```

My .Net Core Code:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AccessPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8079")
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials();
        }));

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseCors("AccessPolicy");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I have tested replacing builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8079") with builder.AllowAnyOrigin() but I have the same result.

Again, it works fine locally, it just fails when the Web API is invoked from  Azure.

Comment: I have tested your code in azure and not found any problem, did you set the CROS repeatly in multiple places?

Comment: Thank @LeeLiu for your help. Your solution works great when the ajax request is simple raw, text/html or x-url-encoding. When is application/json the POST request in CORS is split in two: first OPTIONS method query the server if supports it,  and there after the normal POST. I am having Bad Gateway error using your midleware becouse it do not like the response to the OPTIONS method. But you were right and my problem was specific to this implementation. I published a new project and I did not have the problem. Then I found that I have setup a web.config  with a httpProtocol/customHeaders.

Comment: I am glad to see your problem solved. You can mark the helpful post as answer to help other community members find the helpful information quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can allow CORS enabled in another way and i have tested successfully.

We can create a custom middle ware to achieve this.

First, create a class as our middle ware as below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASPNETCore.Middleware
{
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _nextDelegate;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate nextDelegate)
    {
        _nextDelegate = nextDelegate;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");           
        await _nextDelegate.Invoke(httpContext);

    }
}
}
```

Then register our middle ware in startup class as below.

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
```

[image]

Finally, publish it to azure and we will see what we want as below.

[image]